# Run a Cronjob which create and delete directory on a user home

Tags: linux, ubuntu

How to create a user Bob and create a Cronjob for bob which should create a directory named
test in bob’s directory every hour and delete it after that.

I try to create it on ubuntu by using nano editor but it does not run

Comment: create a simple script and config cron to execute that . `chmod +x script.sh`

Comment: do you want the cronjob to also create Bob? how long should the 'test' directory be there before it is deleted?

Comment: @Pshock13 No! I want that the cronjob will make and delete directory.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [ubuntu.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: `crontab` is a job scheduler and it supposed to run commands, so only way to make something done — is to make a script that will do the job.